# Displacement of DIV after skew

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have DIV after transforming it with skew it gets displaced. How can we get the displaced distanced along the x-axis or horizontal displaced distance[image]

I have placed two divs one below the other for easy understanding. I want to do this on the same div using javascript before and after applying the transform.

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div#myDiv {
  //  -ms-transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* IE 9 */
 //   -webkit-transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skew(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div>
This a normal div element.
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
This a skewed div element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to obtain the size of the element

```js
width_difference=document.getElementById("myDiv").getBoundingClientRect().width-document.getElementById("normal").getBoundingClientRect().width;
console.log("width difference",width_difference);
height_difference=document.getElementById("myDiv").getBoundingClientRect().height-document.getElementById("normal").getBoundingClientRect().height;
console.log("height difference",height_difference);
```

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div#myDiv {
  //  -ms-transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* IE 9 */
 //   -webkit-transform: skew(20deg,10deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skew(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div id="normal">
This a normal div element.
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
This a skewed div element.
</div>
```

Comment: You will also have to do width_difference/2 to get the displacement